# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.github.dandelion.datatables.core.export.ExportProperties

Tags: java, excel, spring, export-to-pdf, dandelion

I am using dandalion datatables with my spring project. I want to export my datatables grid to pdf,excel etc.

So I started with PDF

As per this [link](http://dandelion.github.io/blog/2013/04/24/Integrating-Dandelion-DataTables-in-the-Spring-Petclinic-app/#.U4xFuXYmn_Q)

I followed the steps one by one.

**Step 1 :** Added jar files

datatables-export-itext-0.10.0.jar
datatables-export-poi-0.10.0.jar
datatables-export-poi-ooxml-0.10.0.jar
itext-1.3.jar

**Step 2 :** `Web.xml` Filter adding

```
 <!-- Dandelion-Datatables filter definition (used for export) -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>datatablesFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.github.dandelion.datatables.extras.servlet2.filter.DatatablesFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>datatablesFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

And in jsp

```
 <datatables:table id="roles" data="${list}" cssClass="table table-striped" pageable="true" displayLength="5" filterable="true" processing="true" autoWidth="true" export="pdf">
  <datatables:column title="Id" property="roleId" />
  <datatables:column title="Role" property="role" />
  <datatables:export type="pdf" cssClass="btn btn-small" />
 </datatables:table>
```

But I am getting following error.

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.github.dandelion.datatables.core.export.ExportPropertiesat org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1360)
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1206)
>       at com.github.dandelion.datatables.extras.servlet2.filter.DatatablesFilter.doFilter(DatatablesFilter.java:88)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at com.github.dandelion.core.web.DandelionFilter.doFilter(DandelionFilter.java:157)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
>       at org....

What am I missing??

Please provide any help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from the v0.10.0, the installation steps have changed and the **datatables-servlet2** extra, in which leaved the old `DatatablesFilter` class you've mentionned, no longer exist.

First of all, ensure to have declared all needed components in your `web.xml` file, especially `DandelionFilter` and `DandelionServlet`. Installation guides [here](http://dandelion.github.io/datatables/docs/installation/).
A [migration guide from 0.9.x to 0.10.x](http://dandelion.github.io/datatables/docs/migration/from-0.9.x-to-0.10.x.html) has also been written.

Regarding the export features, it seems you've preferred the filter-based export. In this situation, you have to update your web.xml file as well:

```
<!-- Dandelion-Datatables filter used for basic export -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>datatables</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.github.dandelion.datatables.core.web.filter.DatatablesFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>datatables</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Read more [here](http://dandelion.github.io/datatables/features/export/filter-based-exports.html) about the requirements when using filter-based exports.

By default, the **datatables-core** JAR provides utility classes for XML and CSV formats.
If you want to export in PDF, XLS or XLSX formats, other utilities exist, located in different extras. See the new introduction about export feature [here](http://dandelion.github.io/datatables/features/export/introducing-the-export-feature.html).

Of course, in order to avoid any other dependency issue, I strongly recommend to use a build tool, such as Maven or Gradle.

*(Disclaimer required by StackOverflow: I'm the author of Dandelion)*

Comment: Sir I changed web.xml as you mensioned now my error is `com.github.dandelion.datatables.core.exception.ExportException: Unable to export in the pdf format because the export class com.github.dandelion.datatables.extras.export.itext.PdfExport is not present in the classpath. Did you forget to add a dependency?`
But I have `datatables-export-itext-0.10.0.jar` in my lib folder.... can u plz guide me??? Great thanks to you...

Comment: Could you please turn the DEBUG log level on and post the result? It may be more practical to open a new topic in the [forum](http://dandelion-forum.48353.x6.nabble.com/). :-)

Comment: sir your forum link is blocked in our office cyberorm. com.github.dandelion.datatables.core.exception.ExportException: Unable to export in the pdf format because the export class com.github.dandelion.datatables.extras.export.itext.PdfExport is not present in the classpath. Did you forget to add a dependency?
 at com.github.dandelion.datatables.core.export.ExportDelegate.prepareExport(ExportDelegate.java:92)
 at com.github.dandelion.datatables.jsp.tag.AbstractTableTag.setupExport(AbstractTableTag.java:277)
 at com.github.dandelion.datatables.jsp.tag.TableTag.doEndTag(TableTag.java:139)

Comment: sir it got solved by adding `itextpdf-5.5.1.JAR`.. thank you for your guidance...

Comment: Great! I really suggest you to use a build tool ;-)

Comment: sir i have another problem in I18n please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24011927/dandalion-datatables-i18n-spring-resolver-not-working

Answer (score 0):

looks like the `datatables-core-x.y.z.jar` is missing in your classpath.

Comment: I think some properties are missing... but I do not know exactly what is missing... I made `datatables-default.properties` file in res folder and added global.export.pdf.class=com.github.dandelion.datatables.extras.export.itext.PdfExport But still no luck.... Getting same error.... :(

Comment: Looks like the class is not exisition in version 0.10.0. In version 0.9.3 is is the core.jar. Try the older version.

Comment: I added 0.9.3 and error changed to java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.github.dandelion.datatables.extras.servlet2.filter.DatatablesFilter.doFilter(DatatablesFilter.java:88)