# Dandelion Datatables i18n spring resolver not working

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, internationalization, datatables, dandelion

I have recently started to integrate [datatables](http://datatables.net) in my spring mvc 4 + hibernate 4 + tiles 3 Project.

I want it to display header with various language support.

So I started with this [link](http://dandelion.github.io/datatables/features/i18n/internationalization.html).

As per this page suggests my header shows `???key???` message.

I want to display `Id` in column header but it is showing `???table.header.id???`.

This [link](http://dandelion.github.io/datatables/features/i18n/internationalization.html) says

> If the key cannot be found in the bundle, the ???key??? message will be displayed in the column header.

But I have put following in `datatables.properties`

> i18n.locale.resolver=com.github.dandelion.datatables.extras.spring3.i18n.SpringLocaleResolver
>   global.i18n.message.resolver=com.github.dandelion.datatables.extras.spring3.i18n.SpringMessageResolver

Also  have put in `global_en.properties`

> table.header.id=Id

I also copied same file as `global.properties`.. but not worked.

My jsp file contains

```
<datatables:table id="users" ...>
   <datatables:column titleKey="table.header.id" property="userId" />
<datatables:table />
```

My Resource folder structure is

[image: res structure]

Where should I put `table.header.id=Id`??

Any help is required. Thanks in advance.

**Note:** I am using `AJAX source` + `server-side processing`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### About the location of your messages

You seem to be using the Spring `ResourceBundleMessageSource` with `global` as a basename. So it makes sense to put all translations of header columns in `global_*.properties` files.

### About the `???key???` message

It turns out to be a bug introduced in the v0.10.0.

Waiting for the next version to be released, there is a workaround, but working only with DOM sources.
Here follows the steps.

1) Instead of using the `titleKey` column attribute, you will use the `<spring:message>` tag. Theorically, they do the exact same thing: lookup a resource in your configured resource bundle.

Begin by declaring the Spring taglib in your JSP:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
```

2) Then you need to update the usage of the Dandelion-Datatables taglib. As a workaround, you can use the `<datatables:columnHead>` ([docs here](http://dandelion.github.io/datatables/docs/ref/jsp/columnhead.html)) tag to insert any content in a column header.

Just use it as follows:

```
<datatables:table id="users" ... row="user" >
    ...
    <datatables:column>

        <%-- Everything inside this tag will only appear in the header column --%>
        <datatables:columnHead>
            <spring:message code="table.header.id" /> <== this will appear in the column header only
        </datatables:columnHead>

        <%-- Everything else will appear in all cells --%>            
        <c:out value="${person.id}" /> <== this will appear in all column cells
    </datatables:column>
    ...
<datatables:table />
```

Some observations:

- You need to add the `row` table attribute if you need to access the object of the collection being iterated on, as it's done with the `<c:out>` tag of the JSTL
- You need to remove the `property` column attribute, or the content of the `<datatables:column>` tag will not be evaluated

This is a lot of work for very little return - sorry for that - but waiting for the next version to be released, at least it works.
A [new issue](https://github.com/dandelion/dandelion-datatables/issues/253) has been added.

### If you are using `AJAX source` + `server-side processing`.

Make a variable first

```
<spring:message code="table.header.id" var="titleId" />
```

and added it in

```
<datatables:column title="${titleId}" property="userId" />
```

Also a fix is available [here](https://dandelion.ci.cloudbees.com/job/dandelion-datatables-build/344/). Kindly upgrade to  `0.10.1-SNAPSHOT` version.

*(Disclaimer required by StackOverflow: I'm the author of Dandelion)*

Comment: But this is returning 0 instead of userId in my controller's criteria... the query evaluated becomes `From com.models.UserLogin u ORDER BY u.0 ASC` instead of `From com.models.UserLogin u ORDER BY u.userId ASC`.. this throwing error...

Comment: This isn't working with server side... For any proj server side is necessary to implement... but no i18n support is working..!!!! Please provide some solution.... ASAP....

Comment: Indeed, I forgot to mention that this workaround only works with DOM sources. I'll mention it in my answer. Please edit your answer and mention you're using an AJAX source + server-side processing. This is important.

Comment: By the way, the issue [has been fixed](https://dandelion.ci.cloudbees.com/job/dandelion-datatables-build/344/) and you can give a try to the 0.10.1-SNAPSHOT version. Read [here](http://dandelion.github.io/faq/#snapshot) to know how to use SNAPSHOT versions.

Comment: I found another workaround... please mension this in your answer... I did `<spring:message code="table.header.id" var="titleId" />` and added it in  `<datatables:column title="${titleId}" property="userId" />`... And It worked!!!! Mension this in your answer so I can approve your answer as correct one... :)

Comment: My exports are also not working with server side.. Do I need to jump on `Controller based` from `FilterBased` Exports???

Comment: I am not using maven as maven links are blocked in our office `cyberorm` .I am sorry for that.Can you please tell me which `jars` I need to update and from **where** I can get them?